# Handling Closing event in winForm by calling a button click event results in two different behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a simple winForm and want to consume the closing event and redirect users to logout process. logout process is handling by a button click event. when user press the logout button and choose NO it will remain on the page and user can continue using the app. In closing event I called logout button event method, but when user chooses NO the window closes and the program still running. I'm wondering if the events sent to methods are different or basically why is happening?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myApp {
public partial class frmMain : Form {

    readonly private string password = "user";
    readonly private string username = "pass";

    public frmMain() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(348, 247);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(348, 247);
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        txtPass.MaxLength = 8;
        txtPass.PasswordChar = '*';
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        bool goOn = txtPass.Text.Equals(this.password) && txtUser.Text.Equals(this.username);

        if (goOn) {
            this.Visible = false;
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.Show();
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is not correct", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

    }

    private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
} // end main form
```

}

and the second form after login:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myApp{
public partial class Form2 : Form {

        public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(1032, 691);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(1032, 691);

    }
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
Button btnLogout = new Button();
btnLogout.Text = "Logout";
btn.Location = new Point(10, 10);
this.Controls.Add(btn);
}

private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout?", "Logout",  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
                this.Visible = false;
                frmMain f = new frmMain();
                f.Show();
            }
            else {
                return;
            }
        } // end logout

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
            btnLogout_Click(sender, e);
        }
```

this picture shows the process still running after No option has chosen from the [image: Process still running]closing event, but no window is open.

Checking CMD with `tasklist` command shows the app still running too. `myApp.exe` is in the task list.

Comment: Which branch isn't doing what you expect? The Yes one or the No one?

Comment: @mjwills No one does differently. in btnLogout_Click it keeps the app running and window open, but in Form2_FormClosing close the window but app still running. Yes option works fine.

Comment: How do you know the app is still running?

Comment: In debug session, it still running in IDE. it seems it doesn't exit the environment. I have to stop that from IDE.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Short answer - something (likely a form) has not closed properly (e.g. has been hidden but not closed).

Comment: Why do you create another instance of frmMain in btnLogout_Click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormClosing` Method will close the form at the end you should cancel the form closing process.

try this for **Form2_FormClosing**:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout?", "Logout",  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
        this.FormClosing -= new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosing);
        this.Visible = false;
        frmMain f = new frmMain();
        f.Show();
    }
    else {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

and **btnLogout** click:

```
private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the form closing event, after the form is closed all resources associated with that will be released and form is disposed. To avoid that the Cancel property of the form can be set to true to stop closure of the form.

```
  private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
       button1_Click( sender, e);
       e.Cancel = true;   
    }
```